# grep regex lookahead or start of string (or lookbehind or end of string)

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I want to match a string which may contain a type of character before the match, or the match may begin at the beginning of the string (same for end of string).

For a minimal example, consider the text `n.b.`, which I'd like to match either at the beginning of a line and end of a line or between two non-word characters, or some combination. The easiest way to do this would be to use word boundaries (`\bn\.b\.\b`), but that doesn't match; similar cases happen for other desired matches with non-word characters in them.

I'm currently using `(^|[^\w])n\.b\.([^\w]|$)`, which works satisfactorily, but will also match the non-word characters (such as dashes) which appear immediately before and after the word, if available. I'm doing this in grep, so while I could easily pipe the output into sed, I'm using grep's `--color` option, which is disabled when piping into another command (for obvious reasons).

EDIT: The `\K` option (i.e. `(\K^|[^\w])n\.b\.(\K[^\w]|$)` seems to work, but it also does discard the color on the match within the output. While I could, again, invoke auxiliary tools, I'd love it if there was a quick and simple solution.

EDIT: I have misunderstood the `\K` operator; it simply removes all the text from the match preceding its use. No wonder it was failing to color the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using grep, you must be using the `-P` option, or lookarounds and `\K` would throw errors.  That means you also have *negative* lookarounds at your disposal.  Here's a simpler version of your regex:

```
(?<!\w)n\.b\.(?!\w)
```

Also, be aware that `(?<=...)` and `(?<!...)` are **lookbehinds**, and `(?=...)` and `(?!...)` are **lookaheads**.  The wording of your title suggests you may have gotten those mixed up, a common beginner's mistake.

Comment: I've looked in Linux and OpenBSD implementations of grep and cannot find the -P option. Can you explain it and show it in use and which OS you did it on? EDIT- I found it, it was GNU Grep 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently matching beginning of string is possible inside lookahead/lookbehinds; the obvious solution is then `(?<=^|[^\w])n\.b\.(?=[^\w]|$)`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses the bit regarding losing the effect of `--color` when piping output from `grep`:

> I'm using grep's `--color` option, which is disabled when piping into another command (for obvious reasons).

I ran into this problem while attempting to paginate (i.e., with `less`) `grep` output and see the color output while paging in `less`.

Using `--color=always` *always* "[s]urround[s] the match...with escape sequences to display them in color...," even when piped.

> n.b., when piping `--color`ed output to `less`, it will display the escape characters, as instructed.
> Use `less -r` to see what those escape characters represent.

Example:

```
grep --color=always pattern [file, ...] | less -r
```